# Binding in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-8

Can you explain how can i put binding element and plain text at the same time in a textblock?

```
Text="{Binding following} Following | {Binding follower} Followers"
```

other side

```
 followte.Text = rootObject.following;
 followert.Text = rootObject.follower;
```

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: how can it be more clear?  you will put two binding at  the same time in a same textblock's text property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone doesn't support multi-binding, so you need to use multiple `<Run>`s to bind `TextBlock`'s `Text` to multiple model properties. And you need to set `StringFormat` as well to display the plain-text part :

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run>
        <Run.Text>
            <Binding Path="following" StringFormat="{}{0} Following"/>
        </Run.Text>
    </Run>
    <Run>
        <Run.Text>
            <Binding Path="follower" StringFormat="{} | {0} Followers"/>
        </Run.Text>
    </Run>
</TextBlock>
```

Don't set `Text` property manually when you're using `DataBinding`. That will override the bound value. Set the `DataContext` instead :

```
myTextBlock.DataContext = rootObject;
```

Comment: how can i put '<3 like' in a hyperlink in wp8? <3 will be appbar icon

Comment: @user3555501 You should ask a separate question.